# Kears fit_generator() with y=None

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am playing with Variational Autoencoders and would like to adapt [a Keras example found on GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py).

Basically, the example is very simple based on mnist dataset and I would like to implement on a more difficult set as it is more realistic.

Code I'm trying to modify:

```py
vae_dfc.fit(
    x_train, 
    epochs=epochs, 
    steps_per_epoch=train_size//batch_size,
    validation_data=(x_val), 
    validation_steps=val_size//batch_size, 
    verbose=1
)
```

With more complex datasets it is nearly impossible to load everything on memory so we need to use `fit_generator()` to train the model. But it doesn't seem able to handle this:

```py
image_generator = image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        validation_split=0.2
    )
train_generator = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    dir,
    class_mode=None,
    color_mode='rgb',
    target_size=(ORIGINAL_SHAPE[0], ORIGINAL_SHAPE[1]),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    subset='training'
)
vae.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE
)
```

My understanding is that `class_mode=None` is producing an output similar to the original simple example, but the `fit_generator()` is unable to handle this. Are there any workarounds to deal with the fit generator error?

Configurations:

```
tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
Python 3.6 
Windows 10
Cuda 9.0
```

Full error:

> File "xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 2177, in fit_generator
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
>   File "xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py",
>   line 162, in fit_generator
>       'or `(x, y)`. Found: ' + str(generator_output)) ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`.
>   Found:  [[[[0.48627454 0.34901962 0.2901961 ] ....]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An autoencoder needs `outputs = inputs`. It's different from not having outputs.

I believe you can try `class_mode='input'`.

If this doesn't work, you can create a wrapper generator for outputting both:

```
class AutoencGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, originalGenerator):
        self.generator = originalGenerator
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.generator)
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        x = self.generator[i]
        return x, x
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.generator.on_epoch_end() #this only if there is an on_epoch_end in the original

train_autoenc_generator = AutoencGenerator(train_generator)
```

Both options will need that your model has outputs, of course. If the model was created without outputs (unusual), make it output the results and use the loss function in `model.compile(loss=the_loss)`.

#### Example of VAE

```
inputs = Input(shape)
means, sigmas = encoder(inputs)

def encode(x):
    means, sigmas = x
    randomSamples = tf.random_normal(K.shape(means))                 #samples 
    encoded = (sigmas * randomSamples) + means 
    return encoded

encodings = Lambda(encode)([means, sigmas])

outputs = decoder(encodings)

kl_loss = some_tensor_function(means, sigmas)

VAE = Model(inputs, outputs)
VAE.add_loss(kl_loss)
VAE.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer='adam')
```

Train with the generator:

```
VAE.fit_generator(train_autoenc_generator, ...)
```

Comment: This is a variational autoencoder, so the case is slightly different; the class_mode='input' is different behaviour than the one expected as it gets a bit messed up with the kl loss. Having said that, the wrapper could work with some modifications! will let you know as soon as I try this!

Comment: The KL loss should not be in `compile`, but in `model.add_loss`, while the comparison loss should be in `compile(loss=comparison_loss)`.

Comment: The generator has no relation with the KL loss.

Comment: Gotcha! ok, so ultimately the issue is not with the generator but somewhere else in the implementation! In that case, class_mode=input should be enough (while i revit the architecture)

Comment: @nickthefreak, updated the answer with what I would do. But you can maybe try `fit(generator)` instead of `fit_generator(generator)` and see if `fit` accepts `None` outputs.....